# Entity framework code first and data annotaions

Tags: entity-framework

I use code first approach in my project. In the prject I have classes with MetadataType attribute, which I don't use in my EF model. Class with metadata has some constant public fields (in addition to fields from main type). Now when I tried to query EF it threw exception that in metadata class there fields not mapped... se below in details

```
class M1 
{
    int Id;
    string Name
}

class M2 
{
    int Id;
    DateTime Date
}

[MetadataType(typeof(PageOFSRevenueMetadata))]
class NotRelatedToModel
{
    int Prop1;
    int Prop2;
}

class PageOFSRevenueMetadata
{
    public const string RuleSet1 = "r1";
    public const string RuleSet2 = "r2";

    // Data Vaidation Attrs...
    int Prop1;
    int Prop2;

}
```

In my context I have mapping only for M1 and M2. In the DB exists table with name 'NotRelatedToModel', but I don't want to use it in my model. I use EF 6

Now when I try to make join query on M1 and M2 it threw below exception

'NotRelatedToModel' contains the following unknown properties or fields: RuleSet1, RuleSet2. Please make sure that the names of these members match the names of the properties on the main type

I can move this static fields to another place and it seems to work, but I would like to know why it is happend ? How the EF code first mapping works ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there any property of type NotRelatedToModel in your mapped classes?

Comment: No, there is no any, actully the history is next: I have main assembly with database first approach, I've created the another assembly (plugin) in which I've cretead the code first context. In this plugin I have to use the main (DB first) model and my plugin enity, but they are not crossed. P.S. Code first is not updated DB (I've updated it manually with scripts) I just like flexibility of code first